# How to show Python dictionary data in pyside2 window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I have a list of Dictionaries in python and I want to display those dictionaries data in python pyside2 window in the way that is shown in image attached.

[link of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEUEQ.png)

These are three dictionaries with multiple keys and values, below is example dictionary

```
data = {
    "start time": ["2001-04-27t03:20:15-07:00","2001-04-27T12:20:15+02:00",
    "2001-04-27T10:20:15Z"],
    "Approximate datasets size in the file system" : ["6.940 MB","11 datasets"],
    "Datatypes" : ["APS", "Order APS","Slow Quantity", "Tacho Edges" , "Throughput"],
    "Quantities" : ["Rotational Speed" , "Sound Pressure"]   }
```

There is a list which contain 1000's of this kind of dictionaries and My Problem is how to display them in QT pyside2 the same way as shown in image attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might look something like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = data

        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()             
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.widget)         

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click me")        
        button.clicked.connect(self.onButton)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.grid.addWidget(button) 

    def onButton(self):
        i = 1
        for item in self.data:
            textLeft = f'''
Start time:  
{item["start time"][0]} 
America/Los_Angeles
{item["start time"][1]} Original 
{item["start time"][2]} UTC

Approximate datasets size in the file system:   
{item["Approximate datasets size in the file system"][0]}      
            '''

            textRight = f'''
{item["Approximate datasets size in the file system"][1]}      
Datatypes:
{' '.join(item["Datatypes"][:3])}
{' '.join(item["Datatypes"][3:])}

Quantities:
{' '.join(item["Quantities"])}
            '''

            labelLeft = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            labelLeft.setText(textLeft)
            self.grid.addWidget(labelLeft, i, 0)

            labelRight = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            labelRight.setText(textRight)
            self.grid.addWidget(labelRight, i, 1)            

            line = QtWidgets.QFrame()
            line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
            self.grid.addWidget(line, i+1, 0, 1, 2)
            i += 2


data = [
    {"start time": ["2001-04-27t03:20:15-07:00", "2001-04-27T12:20:15+02:00", "2001-04-27T10:20:15Z"],
    "Approximate datasets size in the file system" : ["6.940 MB","11 datasets"],
    "Datatypes" : ["APS", "Order APS","Slow Quantity", "Tacho Edges" , "Throughput"],
    "Quantities" : ["Rotational Speed" , "Sound Pressure"]},

    {"start time": ["2222-07:00", "2222:15+02:00", "2222:15Z"],
    "Approximate datasets size in the file system" : ["2.22 MB","11 datasets"],
    "Datatypes" : ["APS", "Order APS","Slow Quantity", "Tacho Edges" , "Throughput"],
    "Quantities" : ["Rotational Speed" , "Sound Pressure"]},

    {"start time": ["333-07:00", "333:15+02:00", "333:15Z"],
    "Approximate datasets size in the file system" : ["333 MB","11 datasets"],
    "Datatypes" : ["APS", "Order APS","Slow Quantity", "Tacho Edges" , "Throughput"],
    "Quantities" : ["Rotational Speed" , "Sound Pressure"] },
]  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MyWindow(data)
    myWindow.resize(500, 300)
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. Now I have add checkbox with each record in loop of your code which dispaly that data, and What I want  is after display all the data I would get the data of the record that is checked. I have added this code in your onButton function 
`checkBox_measurement = QtWidgets.QCheckBox() self.grid.addWidget(checkBox_measurement, i , 2)'
Now I am having problem how do I get the checked record.